# Are Apple using COBOL batch processes?

Tags: developer-program, app-store-connect

As a Apple developer I received an invitation to the iOS7 beta. When I logged in, the website said my developer account was expiring "soon", and I needed to renew it prior to accessing the beta program. I found this a little strange, as I have had a membership all year.

But no problem: I renewed the membership. However, I then received an notice saying would take 24 hours to process my account renewal, and to contact them via email if the renewal has not been processed in this time. I have worked as a Project Manager for large banks and insurance companies, and often transactions are processed in batch via COBOL programs on a mainframe.

In banks it is due partially to the number of transactions, but mostly because the systems are old and to update them is a major effort. I am surprised that Apple has the same system, are they also running COBOL batch programs on a mainframe to process membership renewals?

Comment: May or may not have anything to do with the COBOL language.  There's plenty of interactive COBOL out there as well as batched processes in other languages.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here? Speculation on how/why/what Apple may be doing are off topic / not constructive. If you are trying to figure out how to fix your iTunes connect account, that would be constructive in my view.

Answer (score 2):

Apple do not publish information about the technology behind their web site or online services.

It is believed much of Apple's sites are backed by Java based processes stemming from Apple's [WebObjects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebObjects) era.

Answer (score 1):

Unix system administrators often use [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) to schedule processes/jobs to run at certain intervals, and this is most likely what is happening here, and on many sites across the net where actions like mailing list unsubscribe requests produce a similar message saying it will take a certain amount of time for the process to be completed.

Database operations can be "expensive" in time and processor power, as a connection needs to be opened to the DB, the commands need to be executed, returning information needs to be processed, and finally the connection needs to be closed. For a time-sensitive operation like signing up for a site or service, the provider usually opts to run these DB operations in real time, but other, less-sensitive operations may be scheduled to avoid excessive DB open/close requests.